# Bitbake builds C project but does not include dependent libraries to image rootfs

Tags: c, makefile, yocto, bitbake

With the Makefile and hello.bb listed below I am able to compile and run my C project on target device. The issue I am facing is that libraries `sqlite3 libmicrohttpd json-c` are not included to rootfs of the image and I'm getting errors like that:

```
admin@orange-pi-r1:~# /var/hello.bin
Error loading shared library libmicrohttpd.so.12: No such file or directory (needed by /var/hello.bin)
Error loading shared library libjson-c.so.5: No such file or directory (needed by /var/hello.bin)
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_new_string: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: MHD_destroy_response: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_object_add: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: MHD_create_response_from_buffer: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: MHD_queue_response: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: MHD_start_daemon: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_new_array: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: MHD_add_response_header: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_put: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_to_json_string: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: MHD_stop_daemon: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_new_object: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_array_add: symbol not found
Error relocating /var/hello.bin: json_object_new_int: symbol not found
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

hello.bb recipe

```
SUMMARY = "hello"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRCBRANCH = "hello"
SRCREV = "03b9c21ef46973d2a285db785a04620ebaf25db2"

SRC_URI = "git://git@bitbucket.org/hello/hello.git;branch=${SRCBRANCH};protocol=ssh"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS = "sqlite3 libmicrohttpd json-c"

INSANE_SKIP:${PN} += "ldflags"

do_compile() {
    cd ${S}/src && oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/var/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/src/hello.bin ${D}/var/hello.bin
}

FILES:${PN} = "/var/hello.bin"
```

Makefile

```
CC ?= gcc

CFLAGS += -O2
CFLAGS += -I./include
CFLAGS += -I${STAGING_INCDIR}/usr/lib

LDLIBS += -lmicrohttpd -lsqlite3 -ljson-c
LDFLAGS += -L${STAGING_LIBDIR}/usr/lib

cc-headers = \
    hello.h \
    hello_db.h \
    hello_http.h \
    hello_list.h

cc-targets = \
    hello.o \
    hello_db.o \
    hello_http.o

%.o: %.c $(cc-headers)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

all: $(cc-targets)
    $(CC) -o helo.bin $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(cc-targets)

clean:
    rm *.o
```

Comment: Are you saying that the libraries are available at build time but not at run time?  Then you should install them on your runtime system.  If you don't want to or can't do that, then you'll have to link the libraries statically.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes exactly that. I thought build system got that covered for me. I was wrong I guess.

Comment: @MadScientist trying to install missing libraries manually caused this `WARNING: hello-1.0-r0 do_package: libmicrohttpd-0.9.75 was registered as shlib provider for libmicrohttpd.so.12, changing it to hello-dev-1.0 because it was built later`

Comment: I don't know anything about yocto etc. so I can't help with that.  When you link a program, the linker will always look for a shared library to link first by default.  Only if that shared library doesn't exist, will it fall back to a static library.  If you want to force the link to use static libraries you have to add `-static` option to the link line.  Note that this means you have to have a static library installed (sometimes they're in different packages than the shared library) and it's possible you need other options as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEPENDS` specifies build time dependencies.

You need to add `libmicrohttpd` and `json-c` to `RDEPENDS` (Runtime dependencies):

```bash
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libmicrohttpd json-c"
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53596975/10337382) suggests otherwise. And I had tried it earlier, it does not help.

Comment: You need to check the libmicrohttpd recipe and see if it has separate  package for the libraries

Comment: This recipe (libmicrohttpd) ships dynamic libraries itself. Running `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p libmicrohttpd` shows `libmicrohttpd: /usr/lib/libmicrohttpd.so.12`

Comment: Well well well, how did the turntables. You were right all along. I cannot understand why it did not work first 2 times clean-building, but I guess 3rd time is the charm. Thanks!